# PHP - One file or multiple (using require) - difference

Tags: php, performance, require

I have one big PHP code divided into multiple files, each one is loaded with require (exactly one time for each).

I'm curious if it's faster to have one big .php file with the whole code or different parts in different files (each part is always used).

Let's say one thousand people are refreshing the page, how much does the number of files (the code is divided in) change the speed? Which way is faster and why (what does it depend on)?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Why not try both methods and benchmark them to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It terms of processing it really doesn't make a difference, requiring is like copy/pasting the file into the file your requiring it from.

It also keeps your code more organised.

EDIT:

since the require function uses *include path* it will be slightly slower, but not noticeably even with 100000000's of viewers refreshing.

Comment: What about the time needed to find/load the file from the hard disk? Wouldn't that be a problem?

Comment: _uses include path_ <-- finding, as for loading, it'd be loading the same data if it was in the same file :)

Comment: I mean - the other files could be stored on totally different places in the hard disk, couldn't they? It consumes time to "move" there.

But OS should remember the files somehow, right? When they are used over and over again.

Comment: Location shouldn't matter as they are in your webservers cache

Comment: If you are happy with the answer or need more verification let me know ;)